# Hosting main domain and subdomain in the same directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want to host my main site, and my image server in the same directory (I'm on Xampp currently), as they will share a lot of core features and body templates.

I want to be able to open a different index file for another domain/subdomain, like this:
mywebsite -> index.php | imgserver -> image.php

First of all, all domains/subdomains are correctly set in my sys32 hosts file, and apache vhosts config.
My .htaccess however, is where I think my problem lies:

```
# BASE REWRITE
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-l

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mywebsite[NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?query=$1 [QSA,L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^imgserver[NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ image.php?query=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

When loading either of the fake hosts, it still takes me to index.php, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: i can't understand what you want exactly. if possible, show the request url you want.

Comment: I want http://mywebsite/ to go to index.php, and http://imgserver/ to image.php, the ?uery=$1 part will be handled inside those files.

Comment: @StefanKnutsen, could you please confirm if your index.php and image.php files are present in same folder, along with htaccess file?

Comment: You should probably put a space between the host names and the `[NC]` flag (or remove the flag altogether, because clients sending a host name that is not all lower case, is very unlikely.) Also, RewriteConds apply only to the directly following rule - which means, your second rule is completely independent from all those !-f / !-d / !-l checks.